# How do you assign an enum, nested in a class, to a XAML attribute?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Normally, when I assign an enum value to a XAML attribute (usually the "Tag"), I use:

```
<XamlElement Tag="{x:Static local:EnumName.EnumValue}"/>
```

Now, I have an enum defined inside of a class. e.g.:

```
public class MyClass{
    public enum MyEnum {
        enumValue1,
        enumValue2
    }
}
```

I try to assign this in XAML as:

```
<XamlElement Tag="{x:Static local:MyClass.EnumName.enumValue1}"/>
```

and it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To access a nested class/struct/enum in XAML, use `+` as a separator.

```
<XamlElement Tag="{x:Static local:MyClass+EnumName.enumValue1}"/>
```