# wpf ObjectDataProvider with enum in static class

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums

My enum is in module in vb.net (equals to Static class in C#)

```
Public Module EtatAffaire
    Public Enum EtatAffaireEnum As Integer
        Undefined = 0
        Encours = 1
        Receptionnee = 2
        Cloturee = 3
        Facturee = 4
        ClotureeFacturee = Cloturee + Facturee
    End Enum
...
```

And this, in resources

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="OdpEnumStates" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Static Member="model:EtatAffaire.EtatAffaireEnum" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Says "EtatAffaireEnum is not accessible or not reconize".

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

provided method parameter is incorrect. Enum.GetValues expect a `Type` parameter

```
<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    <x:Type TypeName="model:EtatAffaire+EtatAffaireEnum"/>
</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
```

Nested type names are joined by `+` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782160/how-do-you-assign-an-enum-nested-in-a-class-to-a-xaml-attribute))